# Can I programmatically tell when a new tab is opened in the browser?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I'm addressing a problem with an ASP .NET web application where I want to avoid using query strings to uniquely identify dynamic content.  I want to index the content relative to the opened tab/window that is displaying it.  Is this programmatically possible?  If so, what is the compatibility of the approach across multiple browsers?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: This sounds like an awful idea.  Why avoid query string data?  It's a cornerstone of how we communicate over HTTP.  They are *supposed* to be used for uniquely identifying dynamic content.

Comment: Provide an example of the url for you have to use now and the same in the form you wish to produce the same effect. Then it will be clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm in agreement that query strings are the BEST approach, but I've been tasked with trying to create an approach outside of their use.

Comment: If you were on an Apache server, you could utilize mid-rewrite to internally convert a url of the form domain.com/about_us.php?tab=success_stories to domain.com/about_us/success_stories.html
I'm not sure about IIS which you probably are using. Anyway, giving example urls could help identify what is needed.

Comment: *mid_rewrite = mod_rewrite ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  It's not really any different to the user opening a new browser window, or opening the calculator application to work something out, etc.  It happens outside the context of your web page and, short of a browser plugin, you can't get notification of this.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible by "tab" (i.e., browser window instance).

The closest you'll get is to drive new page requests off of session data established in previous requests but that's really a far cry from what you're asking asking for.

I'd tell whomever is "tasking" you with this that <strike>they are a moron</strike> you can't change the fundamental communication protocols of the web.